# Unable to query a local variable in pandas 0.14.0

Tags: python, pandas

I can query an explicit value:

```
fills.query('Symbol=="BUD US"')
```

Now I want to query a variable:

```
In [40]: my_symbol
Out[40]: 'BUD US'
```

In pandas 0.13.1, I could simply use:

```
fills.query('Symbol==my_symbol')
```

This is no longer permitted in pandas 0.14.0 because [local variables must be referred to explicitly](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#api-changes). So I tried

```
fills.query('Symbol==@my_symbol')
```

but this returned an error

```
KeyError: '__pd_eval_local_my_symbol'
```

I was able to change some of my other code to use explicit local variables, but this one just will not take. Any thoughts? The dtype is `object`, if that helps.

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducible example (runnable code that gives this error)?

Comment: @joris `fills = pd.DataFrame({'Symbol':['BUD US', 'BUD US', 'IBM US', 'IBM US'], 'Price':[109.70, 109.72, 183.30, 183.35]})`

Comment: A workaround: it will work if `my_symbol` is a list: `my_symbol = ['BUD US']`

Comment: @KarlD. Hey, that worked! So what broke in 0.14.0? I was able to query it in 0.13.1 as a scalar.

Comment: @KarlD. Ah, saw your comment only now, seems we figured out the same :-)

Comment: This is fixed by https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/12735f9a06a7e3023e94acec88f57eadb4d86ee0

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Seems a bug in 0.14, specifically with strings (works eg with ints). I filed an issue here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7300.
As a workaround for now, you can wrap it in a list:

```
In [40]: fills
Out[40]: 
    Price  Symbol
0  109.70  BUD US
1  109.72  BUD US
2  183.30  IBM US
3  183.35  IBM US

In [41]: my_symbol = ['BUD US']

In [42]: fills.query('Symbol==@my_symbol')
Out[42]: 
    Price  Symbol
0  109.70  BUD US
1  109.72  BUD US
```

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is pretty much right on, but wanted to mention another workaround that I've used in this situation. Basically, just treat the query string like you would any other string where you'd want to insert a variable.

```
my_symbol = 'BUD US'
fills.query("Symbol=='{0}'".format(my_symbol))
```

edit: fixed per your comment

Comment: It actually needs to be `my_symbol = '"BUD US"'`, but this works too.