# Pandas Query with Variable as Column Name

Tags: python, pandas

Passing on new application of information I learned that was part of another question:  [Unable to query a local variable in pandas 0.14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974664/unable-to-query-a-local-variable-in-pandas-0-14-0)

Credit and thanks to user @choldgraf.  I'm applying his answer from the above link differently.

Objective: To use a variable as the column name in a query

Failed examples:

```
import pandas as pd
fooframe = pd.DataFrame({'Size':['Large', 'Medium', 'Small', 'Tiny'], 'Color':[1, 2, 3, 4]})
myvar = 'Size'
subframe = fooframe.query("myvar == 'Large'")
```

The code above returns a key error for 'myvar'.

```
import pandas as pd
fooframe = pd.DataFrame({'Size':['Large', 'Medium', 'Small', 'Tiny'], 'Color':[1, 2, 3, 4]})
myvar = 'Size'
subframe = fooframe.query("@myvar == 'Large'")
```

The code above adds "@" before myvar in the query to reference myvar as a local variable. However, the code still returns an error.

Comment: Is this a bug with pandas, or intended to not work? As of March 2019, I also cannot reference to columns by variables...

Comment: Hi @Thomas, did you see my answer below?  Is that still not working for you?  The question demonstrates two techniques that I couldn't get to work.

Comment: Hi @TempleGuard527, I saw the answer and upvoted it because it works, but was wondering whether any future visitors to this question find a way to make it work with "@variable" instead since this is the intended (and less cluttered) method

Answer (score 24):

Credit and thanks to user @choldgraf. I used the technique he mentioned in another post ([Unable to query a local variable in pandas 0.14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974664/unable-to-query-a-local-variable-in-pandas-0-14-0)) not for the value in the column but for the column name.

A variable can be used as the column name in a pandas query by inserting it into the query string like so:

```
import pandas as pd
fooframe = pd.DataFrame({'Size':['Large', 'Medium', 'Small', 'Tiny'], 'Color':[1, 2, 3, 4]})
myvar = 'Size'
subframe = fooframe.query("`{0}` == 'Large'".format(myvar))
```

(Where backticks are used to bracket the column name, dealing with special characters and spaces in column names.)

Comment: The answer  is perfect. It will only create an issue if the column name has space in it, you can use backtick to overcome

    subframe = fooframe.query("`{0}` == 'Large'".format(myvar))

Comment: fooframe.query(f"{myvar}  == 'Large' ") is also possible.

Answer (score 2):

@TempleGuard527's answer works perfectly. This answer is just an addition with the introduction of `f-string`s from `python3.6`. Now, you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
fooframe = pd.DataFrame({'Size':['Large', 'Medium', 'Small', 'Tiny'], 'Color':[1, 2, 3, 4]})
myvar = 'Size'
subframe = fooframe.query(f"`{myvar}` == 'Large'")
```